# How to not sync states between browser tabs in Jhipster react project

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jhipster

I guess it's about `react-redux` but I'm not very familiar with it.

I generated a Monolithic jhipster-react project using ehcache and h2 database for development. 
When I run it with `./mvnw` and then `npm start` and try to open two browser tabs/windows in `localhost:9000` the scrolling and often entire page and actions get synced, not allowing me to do different things in different pages.

I know that redux is used to save the *logged in* state of the session, right? 
Is there a way to keep only that and **not** sync scrolling and routing etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to [browser-sync](https://www.browsersync.io/) being used in dev. You should not have this issue in prod and also in dev if you open tabs on java backend port (by default 8080). You could also disable browser-sync in `webpack/webpack.dev.js`.

Comment: how do I disable it in webpack? I tried to comment out the `new BrowserSyncPlugin` function but would get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on `localhost:9000`
EDIT: on `localhost:9060` works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

you could add this to your webpack config:

```
        ghostMode: {
            clicks: false,
            location: false,
            forms: false,
            scroll: false
        }
```